# Without using the IVT, prove that if $\text{Dom}f=\text{Im}f=[0,1], f$ continuous, then $f$ has a fixed point

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity

I'd like to know if my approach is sound (also, I'd like to know if there are purely constructive proofs). Let $g: [0,1] \to [0,1], g(x)=x$. We want to prove that the equation

$$g-f=0$$

has a solution in $[0,1]$. The algebra of continuous functions guarantees that $g-f$ is continuous. Suppose that the following were true:

$$0<|g-f| \stackrel{\text{AoC}}{\iff} $$
$$ 0< \epsilon <|g-f| \iff$$

$$  \text{Im}(g-f) \subseteq [-1,-\epsilon) \cup (\epsilon,1]$$

**Option 1**. Since $g-f$ can't be monotone (unless of course $g=f$), $\text{Im}(g-f)$ has to be a disconnected set. If we use the fact that connected sets are preserved under continuous mappings, we're done.

**Option 2**. Without topology, we could look at the preimages of the negative and positive values and construct an alternating convergent subsequence $a_n$ (e.g. by infinitely bisecting $[0,1]$ into subintervals containing infinite representatives of both). Then $f(a_n)$ would be divergent by construction.

Hence, $g-f$ can't be continuous.

Comment: If you use the fact that connected sets are preserved under continuous mappings, then you might as well be using the IVT, as the IVT is just a corollary of this statement plus the statement that connected subsets of $\mathbb R$ are intervals.

Comment: @Aaron : Is it not the converse, the connectedness a consequence of the IVT? // The second option reproduces one proof of the IVT, this is of course also a possibility not to name the IVT while using its contents.

Comment: @LutzL The image of a connected set being connected is the generalization of the IVT to general topological spaces.  Here is a proof of the IVT using it.  Consider the interval $[a,b]$, and suppose that $c$ is between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$.  Then $f([a,b])$ is some connected set that contains $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, and hence contains the interval $[f(a),f(b)]$.  Therefore, $c$ is also in the image.  So we see, it isn't a converse to the IVT, it is equivalent to it.

Comment: @Aaron :  Perhaps a poor choice of words on my side, I read your comment that the connectedness "falls from the sky" and then implies IVT. You are right that both are equivalent. Both the presented options in the question are equivalent to IVT or just alternative formulations.

Comment: @LutzL The bottomline is most of us don't see any point in trying to prove this without IVT. Perhaps OP should say something about the context.

Comment: @Aaron : On the background of the completeness of the real number field, continuity of real functions and the intermediate value property are so closely intertwined that they are (almost?) equivalent. I would say that artificially separating them would be difficult to impossible.

Comment: Of course, examples that IVT does not fully imply continuity exist, see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2727121/115115

Answer (score 2):

The first issue is the first equivalence:

$$0<|g-f| \stackrel{\text{AoC}}{\iff} 0< \epsilon <|g-f|$$

Now, this equivalence is true at any **fixed** $x \in [0,1]$, but you are using further
that this holds for **all** $x$.

Once you prove this claim, a simple modification of what you call "Option 1" solves the issue: since $(g-f)(0) \leq 0$ you get that $(g-f)(0) \in [-1, -\epsilon )$.

Since $(g-f)(1) \geq 0$ you get that $(g-f)(1) \in (\epsilon,1]$. From here it follows that the image is indeed disconnected, a contradiction.

**Hint for** $$0<|g-f| \Rightarrow 0< \epsilon <|g-f|$$

Assume by contradiction that such $\epsilon$ does not exist. Then, for each $n$ there exists some $x_n$ such that 
$$\left| g(x_n)-f(x_n) \right| <\frac{1}{n}$$

Since $x_n \in [0,1]$, it contains some subsequence $x_{k_n}$ convergent to some $a \in [0,1]$. What can you say about $g(a)-f(a)$?

Answer (score 0):

A different approach: If $f(x) \leq x$ for all $x$ then $f(0)=0$. So $\{x:f(x)>x\}$ is non-empty and (by continuity) it contains $(0,r)$ for some $r >0$. Let $A=\sup \{x:f(x)>x\}$. Then $A>0$. If $A=1$ then it is easy to see that $f(1)=1$. If $A<1$ then there exists a sequence $x_n$ in $\{x:f(x)>x\}$ increasing to $A$. Since $f(x_n) >x_n$ for all $n$ we get $f(A) \geq A$. Also, $f(x) \leq x$ for all $x >A$ which implies $f(A) \leq A$. Hence $f(A)=A$.

Comment: This replicates another version of the proof of IVT, besides the bisection proof, so does not really represent an alternative argument.

Answer (score 0):

**option 1**: The statement that $[f(c),f(d)]\subset f([c,d])$ for $f$ continuous on $[a,b]$ and $a\le c<d\le b$ is a generalization of the intermediate value theorem, and includes it.

**option 2**: The bisection method to find a point with sign changes in arbitrarily small neighborhoods (using completeness of the reals) and then using the continuity of $f$ to conclude of a root is one of the standard proofs of the IVT. I'd say that avoiding to cite the IVT by inserting a proof of it is not really what you set yourself as task.